# Nav Walker for materialize css

Tags: wordpress, navbar, nav, materialize

I'm trying to make WordPress theme with the materialize framework but I'm really confused by the navbar part. I've searched on the internet but found nothing, it seems nobody works with materialize.

The only thing that I have found is to make it with nav_walker, like it is done in bootstrap but I don't know how to do it with materialize.

Comment: see this link https://www.34sp.com/hosting-news/blog/wordpress-materialized-creating-material-design-theme-pt-2-customization-colors-styles/

Comment: Already is confusing! :(

Answer (score 1):

I have created a snippet that will allow you to create a navbar for wordpress with materializecss. However, it will not allow you to create children in the menu (dropdown bar). For this, you will need to create a customized nav walker.

The snippet and instructions can be found here:
https://github.com/kristofferandreasen/wp_materialize_navigation

It is based off the site vel linked to in the comments.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it helped me a lot. There is an issue in the jquery intialization example code. constrain_width should be changed to constrainWidth (ie camel case and no underscore)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
<div class="m-container nav">
    <div class="container">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu side-nav', 'menu_id' => 'mobile-nav','items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s"><li class="mobile-header"><p>Menu</p></li>%3$s</ul><div class="clear"></div>', ) ); ?>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'hide-on-med-and-down' ) ); ?>

        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

(Source: see the navigation part of this here: https://www.34sp.com/hosting-news/blog/wordpress-materialized-creating-material-design-theme-pt-1-theme-setup/)

Answer (score 1):

I made this gist, a page index.php where I use the wordpress menu.
I don't believe this is the best solution but is a good start and works fine. Feel free to improve and use it as you wish.

https://gist.github.com/knoonrx/a27381877cfc9e4826fae28ec2544490

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php bloginfo('name') ?></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css">

    <style>
        nav .sub-menu {
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 115px;
            display: none;
            transition: all .3s;
            background-color: #ee6e73;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        nav .sub-menu li {
            white-space: nowrap;
            float: none;
        }
        li.menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<header>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
                <?php
                $menu = [ // mobile side menu array
                    'menu_class'     => 'menu side-nav',
                    'menu_id'        => 'mobile-nav',
                    'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s"><li class="mobile-header"><p>Menu</p></li>%3$s</ul><div class="clear"></div>',
                ];
                wp_nav_menu( $menu ); // mobile side menu
                $menu = [ // desktop menu array
                    'menu_class' => 'right hide-on-med-and-down'
                ];
                wp_nav_menu( $menu ); // desktop menu
                ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>

<br>
<br>

<body>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Materialize CSS Wordpress Sub Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8to3.png)